# “There lie targets” vs. “there lies targets”

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

I have a sentence:

> However, until then it is obvious that there lie intermediate “targets” — foo, bar and baz.

Is the use of *lie* in this way correct? The targets still exist, so I don’t want the past tense.

I don’t think that *lies* sounds correct, because there<s>’s</s> are multiple targets and I'd say *the dogs lie* rather than *the dogs lies*.

Comment: Do you need to use lie? Can't you just say there are intermediate targets?

Comment: @Sam Would it be grammatically incorrect to use `lie`, or just superfluous?

Comment: You have to use a plural verb with a plural subject.

Comment: It's correct, it's just a bit clunky. For instance, you don't say where they are lying. It might help to clean up the sentence if you specify that. Like, some intermediate targets lie *between you and your goal* or in your path, lie intermediate targets.  Without more context, it's hard to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lie* here is a figurative use of a spatial expression. You should use it only if you at some point before or within this sentence define, however vaguely, the “space” in which your targets *lie*. For instance:

> It is obvious, however, that intermediate “targets” —foo, bar, baz— lie on the path toward that ultimate goal.

OR

> It is obvious, however, that before we reach that goal we must pass intermediate “targets” — foo, bar and baz.

If you're not comfortable spatializing your disquisition, I'd stick as Sam suggested with a simple *be* rather than *lie*.

And, yes, plural subjects take the form without *-s*.